# Ext JS Sencha 6.2 , Value to be selected from store as per Radio button value

Tags: extjs

back to stackoverflow for bothering you people. I have written one script containing one Radio Button Group and one Cartesian Chart. I want to get the data from the store for the particular selected value of zone through radio button. This value should only be displayed in chart. Values from rest service are being loaded properly in store Chartdata.js . How it can be achieved please.
BasicZone.js

```
Ext.define('LICApp.view.charts.bar3d.BasicZone', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'bar-basic-zone',
    controller: 'bar-basic-3d',
    requires: [
        'Ext.chart.theme.Muted',
        'LICApp.store.Chartdata',
        'Ext.form.RadioManager'

    ],

    width: 1300,
    bind: '{Chartdata}',


    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        fieldLabel: 'Zone',
        defaultType: 'radiofield',
        isRadio: true,
        inputType: 'radio',
        ariaRole: 'radio',
        listeners: {
            selected: 'getGroupValue'
        },
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        },
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Central Office',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Central Office',
            id: 'radio1'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Central Zone',
            id: 'radio2'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'East-Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'East-Central Zone',
            id: 'radio3'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Eastern Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Eastern Zone',
            id: 'radio4'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'North-Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'North-Central Zone',
            id: 'radio5'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Northern Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Northern Zone',
            id: 'radio6'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'South-Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'South-Central Zone',
            id: 'radio7'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Southern Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Southern Zone',
            id: 'radio8'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Western Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Western Zone',
            id: 'radio9'
        }]

    }, {
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        title: 'Zone - At a glance',
        reference: 'chart2',
        interactions: ['itemhighlight'],
        width: '100%',
        height: 600,
        insetPadding: 40,
        innerPadding: '0 3 0 0',
        theme: 'Muted',
        legend: {
            docked: 'bottom'
        },
        store: {
            type: 'chartdata',
            autoLoad: true
        },
        animation: Ext.isIE8 ? false : {
            easing: 'backOut',
            duration: 500
        },
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric3d',
            position: 'left',
            grid: true,
            fields: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7'],
            renderer: 'onAxisLabelRender1',
            minimum: 0,
        }, {
            type: 'category3d',
            position: 'bottom',
            grid: true,

            fields: ['selected'],

            label: {
                rotate: {
                    degrees: -10
                }
            }
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar3d',
            fullStack: false,
            title: ['Total Users', 'Biometric Enrolled ', 'Authorised Users', 'Devices Issued', 'User Confirmation', 'eFeap Enabled', 'Concurrencia Enabled'],
            xField: 'zone',
            yField: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7'],
            stacked: false,
            highlightCfg: {
                brightnessFactor: 1.2,
                saturationFactor: 1.5
            },
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                renderer: 'onSeriesTooltipRender1'
            }
        }],
        sprites: [{
            type: 'text',
            text: '2FA Biometric Progress - Zonewise comparison',
            fontSize: 22,
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            x: 40, // the sprite x position
            y: 20 // the sprite y position
        }, {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'Source: 2FA Data Server',
            fontSize: 10,
            x: 12,
            y: 520
        }]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`load()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) or [`loadData()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-loadData) method of `store` on [`radiogroup`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html) [`change`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html#event-change) event.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ajf)**, I have used your code and made some change as per your requirement. Hope this will help you or guide you to solve your problem.

```
var chartStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7', 'zone'],
    data: []
});

function getRandomArbitrary() {
    var min = 10,
        max = 50;
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function doCreateData(newValue) {
    var obj = {
            zone: newValue.zone
        },
        key = 1;
    for (; key <= 7; key++) {
        obj[`data${key}`] = getRandomArbitrary();
    }
    return [obj];
}

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Zones',
        columns: 6,
        vertical: true,
        listeners: {
            change: function (cmp, newValue) {
                chartStore.loadData(doCreateData(newValue));
            }
        },
        defaults: {
            flex: 1,
            margin:'0 10'
        },
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Central Office',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Central Office',
            id: 'radio1'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Central Zone',
            id: 'radio2'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'East-Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'East-Central Zone',
            id: 'radio3'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Eastern Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Eastern Zone',
            id: 'radio4'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'North-Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'North-Central Zone',
            id: 'radio5'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Northern Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Northern Zone',
            id: 'radio6'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'South-Central Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'South-Central Zone',
            id: 'radio7'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Southern Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Southern Zone',
            id: 'radio8'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Western Zone',
            name: 'zone',
            inputValue: 'Western Zone',
            id: 'radio9'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        title: 'Zone - At a glance',
        reference: 'chart2',
        interactions: ['itemhighlight'],
        width: '100%',
        height: 400,
        flex: 1,
        innerPadding: '0 3 0 0',
        legend: {
            docked: 'bottom'
        },
        store: chartStore,
        animation: Ext.isIE8 ? false : {
            easing: 'backOut',
            duration: 500
        },
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric3d',
            position: 'left',
            grid: true,
            fields: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7', 'zone'],
            minimum: 0,
        }, {
            type: 'category3d',
            position: 'bottom',
            title: {
                text: 'Zone',
                fontSize: 15
            },
            grid: true,
            fields: 'zone'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar3d',
            fullStack: false,
            title: ['Total Users', 'Biometric Enrolled ', 'Authorised Users', 'Devices Issued', 'User Confirmation', 'eFeap Enabled', 'Concurrencia Enabled'],
            xField: 'zone',
            yField: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7'],
            stacked: false
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks Njdhv, but giving error as : Uncaught ReferenceError: chartStore is not defined
    at BasicZone.js?_dc=1512710689223:90

Comment: Also after making some corrections giving error as : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
    at constructor.coordinateStacked (StackedCartesian.js?_dc=1512714350016:69)

Comment: Can your put your working code on [Sencha  Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)  ? so I can try to resolve error.

Comment: Sorry don't have Sencha account for now.

Comment: you can create it's not difficult task.